# Can multiple transaction be on the same block?

Tags: etherscan

It seems like multiple transaction can be grouped under the same "block" number?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. Blocks are not singular transactions, but a set of transactions. The amount of transactions included depends on the size of the block and the time (average block time is 15 seconds).

Answer (score 1):

[More detailed explanation can be found here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4a3kqo/what_is_ethereums_block_size/)

> Ethereum has a gas limit rather than a block size. The gas limit is a cap on both processing and storage/bandwidth because the cost of a transaction/function is fixed in units of gas for each type of instruction.
>
> The gas limit is voted up or down by each miner and each miner
>   determines what gas price it is willing to accept which is like
>   bitcoin transaction fees but on a per gas basis rather than a per
>   transaction basis.
>
> Here is a chart of some gas related data To figure out how many
>   transactions can fit in a block you dont need to know what the price
>   of gas is. You just need to know how much gas a transaction uses and
>   divide the gas limit by that.
>
> If the network receives a load of spam transactions that start filling
>   up blocks then miners have 2 choices. They can vote up the gas limit
>   to fit in more transactions or they can start increasing the gas price
>   and reject transactions that pay too low a fee. Like with bitcoin a
>   transaction with a low fee might still get through but it would have
>   to wait until a miner that accepts a lower fee (lower gas price) is
>   willing to let it in.
>
> With a sustained spam attack it would just getprogressively more
>   costly to do transactions until either the spammer runs out of money
>   or the miners make so much money that they start expanding the network
>   capacity...